# HTML select option control when disabled is not submitted with the form

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code. I need to gray out this control depending on the selection in another client-side control. I do it like so using jQuery:

```
$('#dropDown1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The problem is that this control, if disabled, is not submitted with the form. Is there any way to overcome this?

Again, I need to somehow be able to prevent user from editing control in certain situations (not all the time) but still be able to submit it with the form.

```
<select name="dropDown1" id="dropDown1">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Remove the `disabled` attribute when the submit button is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a code example showing you how to remove the `disabled` property before submitting the form

http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/dy9Zc/

actually the trick is to just remove the attr on the `submit` event of the form

Comment: Thank you for the example. Again, the issue for me is knowing the ID value of the form element (as I said above I'm calling it from an ASP.NET web app) but there seems to be the way to specify $('form:first').submit(); instead, am I right?

Comment: indeed, `$("form:first")` will do. If you have multiple forms, try to defina a `<div>` with a specific ID arround the form so you can do `$("div#specificId form").submit()`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, enable it upon submit. Since you're submitting the user will not have time to change anything.

Alternately to can copy the value to a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks. How do I enable it before submitting?

Comment: $('#dropDown1').attr('disabled', '');

Comment: No, I mean, what event do I need to override before submitting? You see I do this from an ASP.NET web app so I don't have access to the form element, or its ID...

Comment: Use a regular button, not a submit button. Use "onclientclick" to call a JS function to enable the control, then submit the form.

Comment: You see, the major issue with this approach is if a client-side browser doesn't have scripts enabled. In that case a user won't be able to use the form.