# Select With Disabled Options not being Submitted

Tags: jquery, html

I have 6 Select Input with similar values and labels . Requirement is to disable one label(value) once it is selected in any of the select. I can achieve that using below code:

```
  $('select').change(function()
  {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('option').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('select').each(function ()
      {
         $("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled","disabled");
      });
   });
```

But when i submit the form none of the Select value is submitted.

Any hints on how to resolve this. My Submit action is using simple HTML Submit Button as show below:

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-md pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

My From is very big , so posting some  part of it :

```
<form id="headersForm"role="form" action="/lteUpdteRequestHeaders" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
          <select id="a"  name="a"><option>......</option></select>
          <select id="b" name="b"><option>......</option></select>
          <select id="c" name="c"><option>......</option></select>
          <select id="d" name="d"><option>......</option></select>
          <select id="e" name="e"><option>......</option></select>
          <select id="f" name="f"><option>......</option></select>
    <button class="btn btn-md btn-primary btn-md pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

select options are dynamically generated , removed that part of code for simplicity purpose.

This is not duplicate of existing question as indicated by some friends. Under that scenario user wanted to submit the Disabled Options values or Disable select values.

My question was regarding why I can not submit the value (which i deemed was enabled ) of selected enabled options of selects.

Below 2 solution which both work flawlessly  ,here is another way to achieve this using filter, this is as from another answer on SO:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('option').prop('disabled', false); //reset all the disabled options on every change event
  $('select').each(function() { //loop through all the select elements
    var val = this.value;
    $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function() { //filter option elements having value as selected option
       return this.value === val;
    }).prop('disabled', true); //disable those option elements
  });
}).change();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what are you doing on the submit action.

Comment: Added Form Sample code above , When user selects any option in any of the select it is disabled in all other. Above posted Javascript code works fine on that part only when i submit the form not of the selects selected value is passed to back end.

Comment: Someone voted for this question to be closed , if can specify reason may be will help me more to specify more details.

Comment: Your `<select>` tags don't have a `name` attribute? See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) what this means, specifically the `control name` part.

Comment: sorry i missed those , `<select>` have `name` tag , same as `id`. Updated above

Comment: I see, just wanted to make sure that the html is ok before looking into any js issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML select option control when disabled is not submitted with the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264098/html-select-option-control-when-disabled-is-not-submitted-with-the-form)

Comment: Simillar but different.

Comment: Umm... Your question: The options are not submitted when they are disabled. The duplicate question: The options are not submitted when they are disabled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said in the comments, here is some code (a little bit different from the original...) that does what you want (I hope).

```
$('select').change(function() {

    //enable every options
    $('option').prop('disabled', false);

    //loop though selects
    $('select').each(function() {

        var $loopSelect = $(this);

        //if select value is set
        if($loopSelect.val()) {

            //disabled option matching value in every other select
            $('select')
                .not($loopSelect)
                .find('option[value="'+$loopSelect.val()+'"]')
                .prop('disabled', true);

        }
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybms79ve/

Comment: I agree to the point raised, indeed that should be the reason , but somehow this change only disabled the previously selected Select. For example if a select value xyz in select c , it only disabled that and forgets about the value in select a.

Comment: I think I understand what you want. I'll update soon.

Comment: Here you go. Check the JSFiddle first to see if I understood correctly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For a reliable behavior, you need to have on top a "Pick an option" `<option>` with `value=""` and `disabled` - otherwise you will have trouble with your requirements given the initial state of the selected options of each `<select>`.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  /*
    Get all options from all selects,
    pick the selected ones for exclusion,
    use the selected items to generate an array of selected values
  */
  var allOptions = $('option[value!=""]'),
      selectedOptions = allOptions.filter(':selected'),
      selectedValues = selectedOptions
        .map(function() { return $(this).val() }).get();
  /*
    Loop over all not-selected items,
    if the value is within the selected values make it disabled,
    if the value is not present, enable the option
  */
  allOptions.not(selectedOptions).each(function() {
    if(selectedValues.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <select id="a" name="a">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="b" name="b">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="c" name="c">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="d" name="d">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="e" name="e">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <select id="f" name="f">
    <option selected disabled value="">Pick an option</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah, i just noticed that it won't set options back to enabled, let me check quickly

Comment: Got used to `.prop`, but it's not working with the attribute `disabled` (for checkboxes and `checked` it's the other way round, weird) - script works now

Comment: Will be able to test in a while , will feedback